# Hide address bar and bottom nav on iOS Safari with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, angularjs

I have an Angular JS app running version 1.6.0 on which I would like to hide the top address bar and lower nav bar for Safari on iOS

I looked into this quite a bit but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

I had momentum scrolling enabled using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` but disabled this to see whether I can get the "fullscreen" mode to work.

My current setup in this regard is the following:

**meta tags:**

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

**the following code snippet in my angular module:**

```
.run(function($timeout){

    window.addEventListener("load",function() {
        $timeout(function(){

            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

I have no height or overflow settings on my `html` or `body` tags in the css

Does anyone see what I may be missing?

Comment: full screen mode typically requires a user event to implement in order to prevent abuse

Comment: scrolling down would be the event that I would like to trigger fullscreen